# Cannot download a file off <a> link

Tags: html

I try to put a link to a file in my page, such that, once a user clicks the link - the browser downloads the file.

HTML:

```
<a href="correct_path...." download>downloadable link</a>
```

Here is the image shows the full path of the link:

[image]

And here is the image shows the file does exist:

[image]

**So why, when I click the link NOTHING happens? it doesn't download..**

Comment: what is the exact path / code that you are using? please share that

Comment: @NabeelKhan it contains `PHP` so I am not sure how relevant it is, because I also attached the exact link in the images. But this is it: `href="<?php echo __DIR__ . '/../Files/' . $fileItem['id'] . '.' . $fileItem['extension']; ?>"`

Comment: can you share an example html output that you see?

Comment: Open the developer tools. Look at the console. It probably says something like `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///etc`

Comment: You need to output the link relative to the http:// url of the current page, not the php directory.

Find the http path of the folder and use it instead.

So you should instead use:

    <a href="<?php echo 'http://-path-of-the-directory' . '/' . $fileItem['id'] . '.' . $fileItem['extension']; ?>" download>downloadable link</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with a server (local server too) the root of the urls/links must be the server, not your computer.

For example, in your case, if the root folder of your server is 'SMIS' the correct URL will be "http://localhost/SMIS/Files/6.pdf"